# Pandas and Datetime

Tags: python, datetime, dataframe, indexing

I have two list which I have merged into a DataFrame like

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.column_stack((k_dates[0],k[0])),columns=['dates','values'])


df
Out[73]: 
                  dates              values
0  23-Apr-2018 17:32:21  2.9553240335946986
1  25-Apr-2018 09:06:14   2.729761904599421
```

I would like to convert this df object into a time series to plot values along time.

So far I have tried

```
df.set_index('dates')
df.index=pd.to_datetime(df.index)
```

But I obtained

```
df
Out[71]: 
                                              dates              values
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000000  23-Apr-2018 17:32:21  2.9553240335946986
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000001  25-Apr-2018 09:06:14   2.729761904599421
```

Could you please give a hint please? Thanks

Comment: I think this will go nowhere unless you can show me some expected output. I've tried to explain that what you want isn't really possible because dates and strings aren't the same thing, and that imposing your own format on a date is not possible unless you format it to a string.

Comment: I think my question is clear. Can you pelase set the date column to index into a datetime format. I finally want to obtain a time series object.

Comment: `df = df.set_index('dates').sort_index(); df.index = df.index.strftime('%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S')` you want something like this right?